# Consuming GraphQL API in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: graphql, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Assuming you have a GraphQL API on the back-end, and a Blazor WebAssembly app on the front-end, what is the recommended/best library and structure to use on the front-end (Blazor) to consume the GraphQL API in a clean way? And by clean I mean **other than** using literal strings for the GraphQL queries and sending POST requests using the HttpClient class!

Does anybody have any experience with this stack?